# (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar) returns null

Tags: android, progress-bar

progress bar always return null

```
 public void calcola(View view) {
     final Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(this);
        myDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.calcdialog);
        myDialog.setCancelable(false);

        Typeface typeFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font/Flower.ttf");
        mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);

        TextView calc = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        calc.setTypeface(typeFace);
        myDialog.show(); }
```

this is my xml

```
 <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:maxHeight="30dp"
    android:minHeight="30dp" />
```

the textview in the same layout works perfectly, any idea?

thanks

Comment: you are missing myDialog in mProgress!!!

Comment: You need to inflate a layout to find a view in it ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar) returns null
```

Because You are using `findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);`  **instead of** `myDialog.findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);`

**So your Code Shoud be**

```
 mProgress = (ProgressBar) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to change

```
 mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);
```

to

```
 mProgress = (ProgressBar) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);
```

just as you are doing for your `TextView`. Since you `inflate` the `Dialog` `layout`  you need to look in there by adding the `myDialog.`

Answer (score 3):

If you have progress bar in `calcdialog.xml` use the dialog object to initialize the progress bar as below

```
   mProgress = (ProgressBar) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);
```

`findViewById()` looks for a `View` with the supplied ID in the currently inflated layout. So you set the content of caldialog to dialog. So use the dialog object to initialize your views.

Comment: "If you have progress bar in calcdialog.xml", good call, I made the assumption in my answer, like usual :)

Comment: @codeMagic no you actually din;t op says the textview in the same layout works perfectly, any idea?. So you din't make an assumption. I just wrote it coz i first posted the initialization part and then edited my post

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. Apparently I forgot what I read in the OP after I read your answer, Ha! That's still a good disclaimer to have in an answer like this

Answer (score 0):

you have to check the layout information, in which layout the progressBar is added, and from where you are retreving the ID.
try this:

`mProgress = (ProgressBar) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar);`